# Why am I getting error while initializing rasa

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa

I have installed rasa in my conda virtual environment.
When I run the command 'rasa init' in my conda prompt, I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


    Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
    
    See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
    
    for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
    above this error message when asking for help.
```

What's the issue?!

Comment: Did you read the error message and the help page? The error message asks to include the entire track stace (which I don't see in your post, unless this is really everything that was printed). And the website mentions you should add the "tensorflow" tag to your SO question. That makes it easier to find your question for the persons that can answer your question.

Comment: PS: I also recommend to read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so you can improve your questions and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't installed Tensorflow.

**After opening your Rasa environment with Conda. For me, I named it "rasa_install", so I simply type:**

```
conda activate rasa_install
```

**Then type:**

```
conda install tensorflow
```

Then you might be prompted to install some packages, say yes to them. This should fix your problem. Lemme know if you still get the problem.